# Use of FindRoot iteratively

Tags: equation-solving

I defined an equation F[l] (with l been the unknown parameter) and i solved it numerically using the command FindRoot.

```
FindRoot[F[l] == 115.58, {l, 0.1}]
```

I want to do the same computation equating F[l] with numbers that are part of an array (name DATA) but i don't use the appropriate command (see below).

```
FindRoot[F[l] == DATA[[i, 1]], {l, 0.1}, {i, 1, 330}]
```

Here is the error message

```
"Form of start specification {1,330} in {i,1,330} is inconsistent with other \
start specifications."
```

What is your advise?

Comment: `Table[FindRoot[F[l] == data[[i]], {l, 0.1}], {i, Length[data]}]` ?

Comment: i ll try it and i ll be back

Comment: The error is expected: `FindRoot` is not supposed to "understand" a third argument of the form `{i, 1, 330}`. Also, I would recommend sharing standalone (and minimal) code, it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: One step further, what can i do if i want to change the l predicted value for each array value?

Comment: `Table[FindRoot[F[listOfL[[i]]] == data[[i]], {l, listOfIG[[i]]}], {i, Length[data]}]` where `listOfL` is a list of the `l` and `listOfIG` is a list of the initial guesses.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!