# Use of FindRoot for a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have defined two equations Fs[ls,d], Ts[ls,d] with two unknown parameters (ls,d) and i try to solve them numerically through FindRoot command as follows:

```
Fs[ls_, d_] =0.0742666 d + 190.068 Cos[0.0325387 ls - ArcTan[1.65108 Coth[0.0537241 (200 - 
        d - ls)]]] Csc[0. ls + ArcTan[1.65108 Coth[0.0537241 (200 - d - ls)]]]

Ts[ls_, d_] = 0.0518318 τmax Csc[0. ls + ArcTan[1.65108 Coth[0.0537241 (200 - d - 
        ls)]]] Sin[0.0325387 ls - 
            ArcTan[1.65108 Coth[0.0537241 (200 - d - ls)]]]

FindRoot[{Fs[ls, d] == 222.53, Ts[ls, d] == -0.0012439622995516712`}, {ls, 
        0.1}, {d, 0.2}]
```

The error message is:

```
FindRoot::"frnum": "Function"{-106.78, 0.00124396 - 0.0517293 τmax} "is not a length 2 list of numbers at {ls,d} = {0.1,0.2}."
```

Why the equations can't be solved?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/141462/edit) if you have corrections.

Comment: (1) The complete error message would be helpful. Is it `FindRoot::nlnum`? (2) Since functions in *Mathematica* can return any expression at all, the definitions of `Fs` and `Ts` will probably have to be given.  For instance, substituting at random some built-in functions, everything works: `FindRoot[{BesselJ[ls, d] == 222.53, Log[ls, d] == -0.0012439622995516712`}, {ls, 0.1}, {d, 0.2}]`.

Comment: Definitions for `Fs` and `Ts` are missing from your question. If I just make them up (e.g. `Fs[ls_, d_] := 10*ls + d` and `Ts[ls_, d_] := ls/10 + d`) your code with `FindRoot` works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, but consider the second bit of advice given in [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141363/use-of-findroot-iteratively#comment382017_141363) to your first question. It's more or less the same as I and Pinti have just given. Please read through the [guidelines for asking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking), especially the guidelines for good questions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

In the second equation `Ts[ls_, d_]`  there is an extra unknown parameter `τmax` that's why the system couldn't be solve... So downvote is completely accepted!